# After updating JDK to 17, InternalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry bean cannot start

Tags: java, apache-kafka

On the project, it was necessary to update the JDK to version **17** from **11** and gradle to `gradle-7.3-all` from `gradle-7.0.2-all`. After that, when I tried to launch the application, an error began to appear that the **InternalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry** bean failed to start. Here is the log:

```
2024-03-12 18:08:44,822 [main]   - Application run failed 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) 
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) 
    at some.SomeApplication.main(SomeApplication.java:12) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) 
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) 
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) 
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) 
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:632) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:358) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:326) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:302) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:269) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:243) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:639) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:305) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:338) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:204) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:338) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:312) 
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:257) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) 
    ... 23 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:172) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:157) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:73) 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105) 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:740) 
    ... 37 common frames omitted 
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user 
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:925) 
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:745) 
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:597) 
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) 
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679) 
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677) 
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) 
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677) 
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.login(KerberosLogin.java:103) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:62) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105) 
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158) 
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Here is my **jaas config**:

```
@Component
@Setter
@Getter
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.etl.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
class KafkaEtlProperties {
    private static final String SECURITY_PROTOCOL = "security.protocol";
    private static final String SASL_MECHANISM = "sasl.mechanism";
    private static final String SASL_KERBEROS_SERVICE_NAME = "sasl.kerberos.service.name";
    private static final String SASL_JAAS_CONFIG = "sasl.jaas.config";
    private final Map<String, String> props;

    public KafkaEtlProperties(@Value("${kafka.etl.principal:${spring.datasource.username}}") String principal) {
        props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        props.put(SASL_MECHANISM, "GSSAPI");
        props.put(SASL_KERBEROS_SERVICE_NAME, "kafka");
        props.put(SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, """
                com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
                useKeyTab=true
                storeKey=true
                keyTab="/kerberos/keytab"
                principal="%s";
                """.formatted(principal));
    }
}
```

Keytab and other did not change. When I went back to jdk 11 and gradle-7.0.2-all everything worked again.

I don't understand why this happened and I want to figure out how to fix it.

UPD:
Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.5'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka'

    implementation project(":some-core")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
    }
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.4.2")
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Here "some-core" project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.5'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context-support'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    compileOnly 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-jre'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.6'

    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.4.9.Final'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.9.8'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params'

}
```

UPD 2:
I solved the problem, but not on the Java side. It looks like keytab encryption via `-crypto RC4-HMAC-NT` is already deprecated in **JDK 17**. I encrypted via `-crypto ALL` and now the pods are up. But how can this be solved from the side of the java-service, and not from the keytab? Is there really no backward compatibility for `RC4-HMAC-NT`?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? I suspect a version that doesn't support Java 17.

Comment: show please the pom.xml file and try to us config anntion

Comment: Sounds like same `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login` would be thrown even without Spring. That `sasl.jaas.config` has nothing to do with Spring: that's native Apache Kafka configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886163/how-to-configure-kafka-consumer-with-sasl-mechanism-plain-and-with-security-prot

Comment: The project uses springBootVersion = '2.4.5', there is also an implementation of org.springframework.kafka without specifying the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but not on the Java side. It seems that keytab encryption via -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT is considered insecure in JDK 17. I encrypted via -crypto ALL and now the pods are up, the error is gone.

The following also helped me a lot in answering my question: [JDK 17 (Java 17) +Kerberos authentication fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774313/jdk-17-java-17-kerberos-authentication-fail)